# React redux and authentication

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I have an application with React in front and Express in back, I would like to implement authentication with persistence for user with Json Web Token

in Backend

Login route : If user credentials is good the route send an access token (json) and a refreshtoken (in a cookie http only).
RefreshToken route : This route check the cookie refresh token if its valid it return the user with a new access token

In frontend

userReducer :

```
const initial = {
  logged: false,
};

const user = (state = initial, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNIN:
      return state;
    case LOGIN:
      const payload = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        logged: true,
        ...payload,
      };
    case REFRESH:
      const data = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        logged: true,
        ...data,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And my refresh action for user :

```
export const refresh = () => async (dispatch) => {
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:3000/users/refresh_token")
    .then((user) => {
      dispatch({
        type: REFRESH,
        payload: user.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

My goal is to call the refresh_token route when app is created for check if the user is already authenticated (for keep authentication when user refreshing the page or close/reopen). The only way I found to do that is this code in index.js :

```
store.dispatch(refresh()).then(() => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
});
```

It doesn't work if I put store.dispatch(refresh()) in ComponentWillMount in App because in my render method I check the isLogged state for certain route and it seems that render is called before ComponentWillMount

I don't think it's a good practice to do that, do you know a better way to persist authentication ?

Sorry for my english

Comment: Where is your access token being stored? I think you need another layer of logic in `App` before you start rendering routes to account for this. Typically, you would store some record of the previous session in `LocalStorage` - this can be really simple, like a single boolean value. Then when `App` mounts try to fetch this record and load a skeleton of the application while the authentication request processes. It's not a good idea to block rendering completely because users will end up facing a white screen on slower connections.

Comment: My access token is stored in my userReducer., yes I can put a variable loggedIn = true in localStorage but it's vulnerable, user can change it

Comment: It shouldn't matter - you could use a separate cookie and a browser parsing lib instead if it genuinely concerns you. All the variable is for is to tell the application that there is probably a cookie it can use to reauthenticate, and a skeleton of the private route or a loading screen can be displayed in the meantime. If there is no refresh cookie/invalid cookie or the flag was set by the user then the app just dumps them back on a public route.